How do I hook into the WooCommerce Status = "checkout-draft"
my question revolves around hooking into the new WooCommerce order status draft. This happens when a customer adds products into the cart and views cart/ checkout and it is maintained until an order is placed at which point it changes to pending payment or processing.
What am I missing? I welcome all criticism on the code as much as it's a brief snippet and more-so a solution. If more information is needed please ask. See more info on the status I am talking about here: https://developer.woocommerce.com/2020/11/23/introducing-a-new-order-status-checkout-draft/
I have worked with the other statuses successfully such as
    function track_order_draft_duration($orderID, $old_status, $new_status) {
      //Order details
      global $woocommerce;
      $order = new WC_Order($orderID);

      if ($new_status == 'processing') {
        $msg = "something";
      }
    }
    add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', "track_order_draft_duration", 10, 3);

What I would really like to do is to check every time an order is placed into a cart and has the status of draft as shown below, log the duration before the status is changed, etc.
WooCommerce dashboard

Try below code snippet to do your stuff for order status - checkout-draft
function wc_track_order_draft_duration( $order ) {
    // Check for flag already set or not.
    $has_draft_logged = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_draft_duration_logged', true );
    if ( $order->has_status( 'checkout-draft' ) && ! $has_draft_logged ) {

        // Do your log related code here.

        // And make sure to set a flag with order ID which prevent to override log.
        // So it will logged only once init of draft order created.

        // Once your task is done, set flag for future preventation.
        update_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_draft_duration_logged', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_store_api_checkout_update_order_meta', 'wc_track_order_draft_duration' );

